# Boost arm cross-compilation fails

Tags: c++, boost, cross-compiling

I'm having a hard time trying to cross-compile the boost library to arm platform.
I'm getting the sources from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/ . I've tried ver. 1.55, 1.54, and 1.49 they all behave the same.

After unpacking i use `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/blah/arm-none-eabi`. (the arm-none-eabi catalog contains cross-compilers `include` and `lib` catalogs, amont others.). Next I update the file `tools/build/v2/user-config.jam` by adding `using gcc : arm : arm-none-eabi-g++ ;` (ARM EABI Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-23 crosscompiler, gcc version 4.7.3). After that, I run `./bjam --prefix=/blah/arm-none-eabi/ toolset=gcc-arm`. This gives me a lot of errors like:

```
`"arm-none-eabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/wave/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/wave_config_constant.o" "libs/wave/src/wave_config_constant.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/wave/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/wave_config_constant.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/wave/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/cpplexer/re2clex/aq.o
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-pthread'`
```

I modified the file `$BOOST/tools/build/v2/tools/gcc.jam`

```
-case *       : option = -pthread ; libs = rt ;
+case *       : option = -lpthread ; libs = rt ;
```

After running the cross compilation again i get a lot of

```
"arm-none-eabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pedantic -lpthread -fPIC -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -pedantic -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/chrono/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/chrono.o" "libs/chrono/src/chrono.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/chrono/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/chrono.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/chrono/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/thread_clock.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/chrono/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/process_cpu_clocks.o
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/chrono/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/chrono/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>chrono.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/chrono/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_chrono.so for lack of <pstage/lib>libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0...
gcc.link.dll bin.v2/libs/context/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/libboost_context.so.1.54.0
/home/skramer/PP/MGR/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    "arm-none-eabi-g++"    -o "bin.v2/libs/context/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/libboost_context.so.1.54.0" -Wl,-h -Wl,libboost_context.so.1.54.0 -shared -Wl,--start-group "bin.v2/libs/context/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/asm/make_arm_aapcs_elf_gas.o" "bin.v2/libs/context/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/asm/jump_arm_aapcs_elf_gas.o"  -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lrt -Wl,--end-group -lpthread 

...failed gcc.link.dll bin.v2/libs/context/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/libboost_context.so.1.54.0...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_context.so.1.54.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/context/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi>libboost_context.so.1.54.0...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_context.so for lack of <pstage/lib>libboost_context.so.1.54.0...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/coroutine/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/detail/standard_stack_allocator_posix.o
libs/coroutine/src/detail/standard_stack_allocator_posix.cpp:14:22: fatal error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

 "arm-none-eabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -lpthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/coroutine/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/detail/coroutine_context.o" "libs/coroutine/src/detail/coroutine_context.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/coroutine/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/detail/coroutine_context.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/coroutine/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_coroutine.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/coroutine/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>detail/standard_stack_allocator_posix.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/coroutine/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_coroutine.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/coroutine/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>detail/standard_stack_allocator_posix.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_coroutine.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/coroutine/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_coroutine.a...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o
gcc.link.dll bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/libboost_date_time.so.1.54.0
/home/skramer/PP/MGR/arm-2013.05/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't really know what to do now. I've been googling around for a few hours but with no result. I've tried using b2 instead of bjam - nothing changed. I've also tried a different arm cross-compilator - Xilinx EABI Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.03-83 (gcc 4.6.3) which seems to be producing less errors but still a lot of syntax and No such file or directory like errors are present. How can I get boost working at arm platform?

Comment: Looks like you need `-std=c++11` compiler option set (`-pthread` is only supported along this AFAIK). Which GCC version are you using actually? We're building the latest GCC (4.8) ARM cross-toolchain versions ourselves actually.

Comment: May be this link helps (it describes building the cross-toolchain with GCC 4.7 but there's not really a difference for GCC 4.8): http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2013/09/building-gcc-471-arm-cross-toolchain-on.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added -std=c++11 to gcc.jam (e.g. `"arm-xilinx-eabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -std=c++11 -pthread  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/wave/build/gcc-arm/release/link-static/threading-multi/token_ids.o" "libs/wave/src/token_ids.cpp"`) but I still keep getting the errors about unrecognized option '-pthread'. The link you provided uses configure, which is not possible to use with boost. Any other ideas maybe?

Comment: `-std=c++11` is not fully implemented by GCC 4.7 (especially not all of the `std::thread` parts). The link I sent you describes how to build the **GCC toolchain**, which hasn't anything to do with the boost build process itself.

Comment: Ok, i get it now. I'll give it a shot and let you know!

Comment: @πάντα -pthreads is not necessarily related to c++11 threads.

Comment: Which part of `cannot find -lrt` is most difficult?

Comment: @n.m. But only supported since GCC 4.8 AFAIK ...

Comment: @πάντα no, not really.  Try 2.90.

Comment: so is creating a gcc 4.8 cross compiler necessary? How to fix the rt library? I can't find it in the file system.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Or do you mean support specifically for the arm target?

Comment: @n.m. At least that's what I've been noticing for arm target, yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it's because the "none" part, not because of the "arm" part. Pthreads support is OS-specific. One need to target e.g. arm-linux.

Comment: @n.m. You're right, I've been supposing that (linux is used). We have our own pthreads implementation/abstraction for the 'arm-none-eabi' systems. I doubt it would interwork with boost correctly, never tested to compile it in this environment.

Comment: How does the none\linux part affect the tool? Does it change the features offered by the cross compiler?

Comment: @SebastianKramer just for your reference, have you already tried to develop your software using some embedded Linux distro, that will take care about cross-compiler and needed libraries, like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) or [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) flavor. You can even use your existing toolchain. I see so many questions about how to cross-compile OpenCV, Qt etc per hand. Actually people just want to develop their software using these tools/libs and don't bother with cross-compilation.

Comment: I'd prefer to stick to the cross compile approach. That's no fun if you don't know what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I've finally managed to compile and run a gcc 4.8.2 based arm-linux-eabi cross compiler but it also does report errors about missing libraries. Which cross compiler should I use for compilation? Has anybody got a proven to work arm cross compiler which would be suitable to compile boost library?

Comment: FYI: I've managed to compile boost using linaro gcc 4.8.2 arm cross compiler. I've updated the project-config.jam instead of user-config.jam, as advised at http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/10/03/cross-compiling-boost-c-libraries-for-arm/ . Thanks everyone for putting an effort!

Answer (score 0):

1. `error: 'sys/mman.h: No such file or directory` - the compiler can not find header 'sys/mman.h' because the include path is not correct or your system does not contain this file.
2. You compile for an embedded system, e.g. arm-non-eabi (used for bare-metal). This ABI is not supported by boost.context. To disable buidling boost.context and boost.coroutine (depends on boost.context) you have to call: `b2 --without-context --without-coroutine`

Comment: The library is present in /usr/include/sys as it supposed to be, the library I couldn't find was rt.h . I'll give a shot to your b2 invocation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I keep getting errors about unrecognized pthread option, with and without the `std=c++11` option. Maybe any other thoughts?